# Unittest for flask app not running as expected

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, flask, web-development-server

I have created a simple unit test for my flask app, these tests are saved in a different folder, and then called from the manage.py file. However, when I run the tests, none of the test functions is executed.

Here is the test.py file:

```
from flask import current_app
import unittest
from app import create_app, db

class BasicTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app=create_app('testing')
        self.app_context=self.app.app_context()
        self.app_context.push()

    def tearDown(self):
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()
        self.app_context.pop()

    def test_app_exists(self):
        self.assertFalse(current_app is None)
    
    def test_app_is_testing(self):
        self.assertTrue(current_app.config['TESTING'])
```

Also here is the manage.py file.

```
from app import create_app

app=create_app('default')


def test():
    import unittest
    tests=unittest.TestLoader().discover('tests')
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(tests)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When I run the `test()` function from the command line, I get the following response.

```
`----------------------------------------------------------------------
 Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

 OK`
```

Is there something is am doing wrong?